# Parsing JSON in Jade?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, postgresql

I have ben scratching my head. I am trying to parse JSON in Jade. I have tried about 20 solutions I found on Stack... does anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

route (data from postgres):

```
//show books
pg.connect(dbconnect, function(err, client, done) {

    client.query('SELECT * FROM books', function(err, result) {
        res.render('books', { title: 'My Books', booklist: JSON.stringify(result.rows) });
    });

});
```

Jade:

```
 block content
    each key in booklist
        p= bookname
```

Output:

```
[{"id":1,"bookname":"Book 1"},{"id":2,"bookname":"Book 2"}]
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You don't state your problem at all. You definitely state there is a problem, but you don't state the problem.

Comment: Sure. The JS loop ( each key in booklist) isnt returning or printing anything to the page. There are no errors on the console either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely that you cast your object to a string with `JSON.stringify()`. That function will return a string, which you then are trying to iterate over.

Try

```
pg.connect(dbconnect, function(err, client, done) {
    client.query('SELECT * FROM books', function(err, result) {
        res.render('books', { title: 'My Books', booklist: result.rows });
    });
});
```

and

```
block content
   each book in booklist
       p= book.bookname
```

Comment: My god ;) Thank you SO much Oskar.